# Identity: write the infimum as an integral

Tags: integration, analysis, proof-verification, self-learning

In the proof I'm trying to elaborate I want to write the infimum/minimum as
$$\inf\{\alpha,e,f\}=\int_0^\alpha \chi_{(-\infty,\inf(e,f)]}(z)dz,$$
where $\alpha,e,f\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\chi$ is the indicator function, because then it would make the rest easier.

Is it enough to argue that 
$$\int_0^\alpha \chi_{(-\infty,\inf(e,f)]}(z)dz=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{lc}
\alpha &,\ \text{if} \ \alpha \leq \inf\{e,f\} \\
\inf\{e,f\}&,\  \text{if} \ \alpha > \inf\{e,f\}
\end{array}?
\right. $$

Could you please answer if it is the case or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks reasonable to me! I wonder though how this might make things easier :).

Comment: @hal4math Thanks for your answer! The reason it makes things easier is not trivial, but if I write $\inf\{2\alpha,e,f\}=\int_0^{2\alpha}\chi_{(-\infty,e]}(z)\chi_{(-\infty,f]}(z)dz$ I can prove the "Rio's inequality" for covariance. But there are other ways to do what I'm trying to do, surely. *I thought this question was trivial to most of people here, but only you commented on it.

Comment: I don't like the word _trivial_ to much. But I guess you mean it in the sense of obvious. Maybe that's why some didn't bother to confirm. But I totally get that especially those "obvious" question need confirmation!

Comment: @hal4math It is so obvious that people don't even know the answer.